# How to click a button lying below UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

say, I have a button lying under `UITableView`, how can I click the button through the `UITableViewCell` but do not trigger the cell click event:

[image]

The reason I put the button behind the tableview is that I want to see and click the button under the cell whose color set to be clear, and when I scroll the table, the button can be covered by cell which is not with clear color

Comment: bring the button over the tableView is easiest way, why not?

Comment: Language ObjC or Swift?

Comment: @Tj3n  the reason is a little complicated, but I have to do like this ~

Comment: @Mr.UB  I use swift ~

Comment: Do you mean the button is behind the table or is it part of the table cell?

Comment: @rmaddy behind the table

Comment: @rmaddy he said its behind tableView. Well i guess you can, I think the only way here is subclass the tableView and override `hitTest` to allow the tableview can scroll while disable touch on that exact button location

Comment: Why is it behind the table? Are the cells transparent? You can't tap on a view that is behind another.

Comment: @Tj3n No, they said it's below (and under) the table which is an ambiguous term here since below (and under) can mean lower (in the y coordinate) or behind (in the z coordinate). That's why I asked for clarification.

Comment: @rmaddy I have made the cell transparent, but the cell will absorb the touch event

Comment: what  is the problem if button remains on top, i mean not under the tableview ?

Comment: @Lion briefly speaking, I want to see and click the button under the cell whose color set to be clear, and when I scroll the table, the button can be covered by cell which is not with clear color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a sample project and got it working:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TableViewVC.handleTap))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func handleTap(touch: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    let isPointInFrame = CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, touchPoint)

    print(isPointInFrame)

    if isPointInFrame == true {
        print("button pressed")
    }
}
```

To check of button is really being pressed we need to use long tap gesture:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let tap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TableViewVC.handleTap))
    tap.minimumPressDuration = 0.01
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}


func handleTap(touch: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    print(" pressed")
    if touch.state == .Began {
        let isPointInFrame = CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, touchPoint)
        print(isPointInFrame)

        if isPointInFrame == true {
            print("button pressed")
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        }
    }else if touch.state  == .Ended {

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the button look like "really" being clicked?

Comment: no it is not possible !! for that your button should be on top not under tableview

Comment: I think that by using the UILongPressGestureRecognizer, the tableView can't scroll.

Comment: @Mr.Bista Yes. By using your solution with UITapGestureRecognizer everything works as expected. But if i use UILongPressGestureRecognizer, the swipe gesture is being captured by the handleTap method. So the scrolling does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Get the touch point on the main view. Then use following method to check the touch point lies inside the button frame or not.

```
bool CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect rect, CGPoint point)
```

Comment: This is one idea, but you should put it in `touchesBegan` or something and after check send the action programatically with `button.sendActionsForControlEvents`

Answer (score 2):

You can write your custom view to touch button or special view behind the topview

```
class MyView: UIView {

    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        for subview in self.subviews {
            if subview is UIButton {
                let subviewPoint = self.convertPoint(point, toView: subview)
                if subview.hitTest(subviewPoint, withEvent: event) != nil { // if touch inside button view, return button to handle event
                    return subview
                }
            }
        }
        // if not inside button return nomal action
        return super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```

Then set your controller view to custom MyView class

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I want ~